# Probability distribution of bitwise-&

Tags: distinguisher

Does the bitwise-& between two uniformly distributed input produce an output that seems uniformly distributed ? To be more specific, assume to take x and y uniformly from {0,1}^n and compute z = x & y. Assume then to uniformly choose a w from {0,1}^n. 
Do z and w have the same distribution over {0,1}^n ?

Comment: Take the case $n=1$ and compute the probability of the output depending of the different inputs. That should give you a beginning of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very.  A few lines of code produces this for `a & b` with both variables uniformly distributed across $2^8$:-

[image: histogram]

I don't think that it has a specific distribution name, other than a classic *"bitwise AND function"*.

---

From :-

```
for x in range(256 * 256):
    a = random.randrange(pow(2, 8))
    b = random.randrange(pow(2, 8))
    results.append(a & b)
```